# Why are all magicians female?

Tags: brynhildr-in-the-darkness

In Brynhildr in the Darkness, all of the *magicians* seem to be female - but there doesn't seem to be a reason for this (in the manga at least).

If we look at Okamoto Lynn's other work, Elfen Lied, he explains that male Diclonius are possible, but lack the vectors that the females have due to inbreeding. This explains why they are not that commonly seen in the series. I haven't been able to find a similar reason for Brynhildr though.

[Reference for Elfen Lied](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Juhachi/Diclonius)

Is there any similar reasoning for why all the magicians are female in Brynhildr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magicians are all female to give the main character a harem of course.

It's not explained as to why all the magicians are only female. This could be due to compatibility issues with the alien monsters, or it could simply be personal preference on the kidnappers part, we don't know.